# Laravel addOrUpdate() on basis of related table values?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Below is something I am trying to do:

I have `users` table and `user_profiles` table and I am inserting `name`, `email` in `users` table and `phone`, `address, .... etc` in `user_profiles` table.

I have to match each value to prevent duplication of user, I have found this laravel method `addOrUpdate()` but it works only for one table. But I have to match `user_profiles` values too i.e `phone,address`.

Below is example code

```
                $result = $customer->updateOrCreate([
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'city_id' => $request->city_id,
                    'area_id' => $request->area_id,
                    'email' => $request->email
                ], [
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'city_id' => $request->city_id,
                    'area_id' => $request->area_id,
                    'email' => $request->email
                ]);
```

There any way to achieve this using Laravel techniques?

Regards

Comment: I assume email should be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a `relationship` with `user` and `user_profiles` model like-

```
public function userProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\UserProfile','user_id','id');
}
```

And then in your `post controller` as you want to `match` each value to prevent `duplication` of user-

```
$result = User::where('name',$request->name)->where('email',$request->email)
       ->whereHas('userProfile', function($q) use ($request){
            $q->where('city_id'$request->city_id)->where('area_id',$request->area_id)

  )->first();
if(!$result){
     ////your registration here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a user with exactly the same data exists, you can't use `updateOrCreate()`. Do this instead:

```
$user = User::where('name', $request->name)->where('email', $request->email)->first();
$profile = $user->profile()->where('phone', $request->phone)->where('address', $request->address)->count();
if ($user && $profile) {
    // User exists.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Laravel's  Validator Facade. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators

This would check to make sure the name and email fields of the `users` and `users_profile` table are unique.

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|unique:users|unique:users_profile',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|unique:users_profile',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `updateOrCreate` for both of your models for sake of uniqueness i  assume email should be unique so first `updateOrCreate()` method will check if user exists for parameter `$request->email` then update if not then create and return user model instance (in both update/create case)

Second `updateOrCreate()` on `UserProfile` will check if there exist any data for `user_id` then update else add new row, I assume `user_id` will be a foreign key in user profile table

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate([
                    'email' => $request->email
                ], [
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'email' => $request->email
                ]);
UserProfile::updateOrCreate([
                    'user_id' => $user->id
                ], [
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'city_id' => $request->city_id,
                    'area_id' => $request->area_id
                ]);
```

Comment: what will happens if user data match but user_profiles data doesn't??

Comment: @Sohel0415 see second para in my answer *Second updateOrCreate() on UserProfile will check if there exist any data for user_id then update else add new row*

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid but he want exact matching i guess, that means if email match but others doesn't, then new record will be inserted

Comment: @Sohel0415 that is why at first place i have added my assumption *for sake of uniqueness i assume email should be unique so first*

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I think this conclude my question, thanks for explaining patiently.